# Excel VBA macro is giving me an overflow error 6

Tags: vba, excel, overflow

I have a macro that combines cells in a range based on their borders.  It was working fine until I realized it didn't account for the properties of the text (specifically the bold font).  I added the second part to the macro, and for some reason I'm getting an overflow.  Here is the macro:

```
    Sub TestMacro()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim outputText As String
    Dim strDelim As String
    strDelim = "XXXX"

    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = False


    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            If outputText <> "" Then
                c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = outputText
                FixBold c.Offset(-1, 1), strDelim
            End If
            outputText = IIf(c.Font.Bold, strDelim, "") & c.Value & IIf(c.Font.Bold, strDelim, "")
        Else
            outputText = outputText & " " & IIf(c.Font.Bold, strDelim, "") & c.Value & IIf(c.Font.Bold, strDelim, "")
        End If
    Next c

    If outputText <> "" Then
        With Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1)
            .Value = outputText
            FixBold .Cells(1), strDelim
        End With
    End If

End Sub


Sub FixBold(r As Range, strD As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim sVal As String
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim boolBold As Boolean

    sVal = Replace(r.Value, strD & " " & strD, " ")
    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, strD, "")
    i = InStr(1, sVal, strD)
    While i > 0
        j = InStr(i + 1, sVal, strD)
        r.Characters(Start:=i - 2 * k * Len(strD), Length:=j - i - Len(strD)).Font.Bold = True
        i = InStr(j + 1, sVal, strD)
        k = k + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

I believe the overflow error is coming from "r.Characters(Start:=i - 2 * k * Len(strD), Length:=j - i - Len(strD)).Font.Bold = True" towards the bottom.

Comment: Can you run your code step by step using F8 and tell us what line is causing the problem?

Comment: So I did that.  Turns out the While loop containing what I thought was the error is an infinite loop.

Comment: Well my friend, you need to add an exit statement inside your loop nested within a conditional statement. Use do while loop instead of while  wend. You can't exit a while loop. It'd be something `Do While CONDITIONISTRUE DoStuffHEREFirst If eXITConditionisTrue Then DostuffHereAnd Exit Do EndIf DostuffhereTooIncaseYouneed Loop`

Answer (score 0):

I had experimented with the following input and received an overflow after too long:

[image: Cell #1: "The quick brown"; Cell #2: "FOX"; Cell #3: "jumps over the lazy dog"]

To cut a long story short, your `While` condition checks to ensure that `i` is greater than zero, but `i` will switch between the occurrences of `"XXXX"` rather than reach zero.

If `i` is currently at the last match of `"XXXX"` within `sVal`, `j` will be assigned to the position of the next match. However, `j` will be assigned to the next match. Since there isn't one, it is assigned 0, from which `i` can be assigned to the *first* match all over again. This continues until `k` exceeds 32767, the upper limit for a signed 16-bit integer.

This aside, all that your code is presently doing is making each section bold, regardless of whether the corresponding cell is bold or not. I will post improved code in an update in a separate answer if I get the chance, but I trust that this at least explains the overflow error.

We will iterate through this to find out exactly what is going on.

**Initialisation**

```
sVal = "The quick brown XXXXFOXXXXX jumps over the lazy dog"
boolBold = undefined
i = 17
j = undefined (0)
k = undefined (0)
s = undefined (Empty)
```

**First pass**

```
sVal = "The quick brown XXXXFOXXXXX jumps over the lazy dog"
boolBold = False
i = 24
j = 23
k = 1
s = Empty
```

**Second pass**

```
sVal = "The quick brown XXXXFOXXXXX jumps over the lazy dog"
boolBold = False
i = 17
j = 0
k = 2
s = Empty
```

**Third pass**

```
sVal = "The quick brown XXXXFOXXXXX jumps over the lazy dog"
boolBold = False
i = 24
j = 23
k = 3
s = Empty
```

**Fourth pass**

```
sVal = "The quick brown XXXXFOXXXXX jumps over the lazy dog"
boolBold = False
i = 17
j = 0
k = 4
s = Empty
```

Comment: Come to think of it, `i - 2 * k * Len(strD)` and `j - i - Len(strD)` _might_ have been factors — the `Start` and `Length` parameters are 32-bit signed integers and cannot exceed (2<sup>31</sup>–1). Basically the problem is `k` getting too large.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be more suitable — take particular note of `FixBold(r,rs)`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMacro()
    ' Assumes that:
    '   - Selection is contiguous

    Dim c As Range
    Dim outputText As String
    Dim groupedRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set groupedRange = Nothing                      ' The range which feeds outputText
    lastRow = Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.Count  ' The final row in Selection (relative to start)

    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Clear
    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
    Selection.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Font.Bold = False


    For Each c In Intersect(Selection.Rows.Cells, Selection.Columns(1).EntireColumn)
        If c.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            If outputText <> "" Then
                c.Offset(-1, 1).Value = outputText
                FixBold c.Offset(-1, 1), groupedRange
            End If
            outputText = c.Value
            Set groupedRange = c
        Else
            outputText = outputText & " " & c.Value
            ' Assign to the group
            If Not groupedRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Set -- combine with c
                Set groupedRange = Union(groupedRange, c)
            Else
                ' Unset -- Union(a,b) with null parameters throws an error
                Set groupedRange = c
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If outputText <> "" Then
        With Selection.Cells(Selection.Cells.Count).Offset(0, 1)
            .Value = outputText
            FixBold .Cells(1), groupedRange
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Sub FixBold(r As Range, rs As Range)
    ' Iterate through the cells in supporting range rs
    ' For each cell in rs which is formatted bold,
    '   update the corresponding formatting in r
    ' We won't need a string delimiter here

    If rs Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  ' Ignore this if rs wasn't given

    Dim c As Range  ' Cell iterator variable
    Dim l As Long   ' Cell length
    Dim lt As Long  ' Elapsed length (remember to include space between cells)

    lt = 1

    For Each c In rs.Cells

        l = Len(c.Text)
        If c.Font.Bold And l > 0 Then
            r.Characters(lt, l).Font.Bold = True
        End If
        lt = lt + l + 1

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: You can adapt `FixBold` to apply more settings if you wish, basically until the subroutine's name becomes a misnomer. :)